# Ag Grid Header Separator

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Can anyone help me to apply custom style to Ag-grid header separator In Angular. Using border-right property its applying style to last column as well, In my case last column header should not have separator. Using not and last child clause its disturbing the CSS.

Please help me to apply custom style to Ag grid header separator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the answer: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-headers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **headerClass** property in column definition.

Refer this documentation about column properties:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/